# How do I get the output of Savant3 template into a string?

Tags: php, savant3

How do I get a Savant3 template to render to a string rather than just output it directly to the web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **fetch** method rather than the usual **display** method.

```
$my_template_output = $tpl->fetch('mytemplate.tpl.php');
```